# insert data view is grey out in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding

I create a page in pages not site pages in SharePoint 2013 and when I want to edit in advanced mode and insert data view it is gray out what should I do I check in and check out it several times but it does not change.

What should I do?

Comment: what's the type of your page ? is it web part page ?

Answer (score 5):

**Try to do the following:**

- Check out your page.
- Right-click and Edit file in an advanced mode.
- From the above ribbon > Click on code view tools > Click on **Parse HTML**.

[image]

- Go back to insert tab > The Data view should be now enabled.

**If the data view still disabled,**

- Make sure that you are trying to add data view in the correct place within `Web Part Zone` below `<ZoneTemplate>` then click on **Parse HTML** and The Data view should be now enabled.
- If **The current site Master Page is Oslo Master Page**. It looks like a bug in SharePoint designer 2013 where you can't add DataView to a page in a site that has Oslo Master Page.

> Check other root causes and the detailed steps at **[Data View disabled in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/dataview-is-disabled-sharepoint-designer-2013/)**

Comment: I tried but it doesnot work

Comment: what's the type of your page ? is it web part page ?

Comment: I think I click on page On blue ribbon on top of the page and then click add

Comment: Check other root causes at **[Data View disabled in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/dataview-is-disabled-sharepoint-designer-2013/)**